# Can't use the value obtained by calling getResponseHeader

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey, getresponse

I'm having problems to use the value which I obtain when I call `getResponseHeader` on my Greasemonkey script.

First of all, I have declared the following global variables:

```
size = 0;
maxS = 153600; // Max. size (bytes).
```

Once the website has been completely loaded, my main function is called and inside of it I get all images within a certain div (which is not shown here because it's not relevant):

```
function main() {
    ...
    var imgs = posts[i].getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var j = 0; j < imgs.length; ++j) {
        getFileSize(imgs[j].src, responseHandler);
        if (size > maxS)
            // Do something
    }
    ...
}
```

And this is how `getFileSize` works:

```
var getFileSize = function(address, responseHandler) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('head', address, true);
    req.onreadystatechange = responseHandler;
    req.send(null);
};

var responseHandler = function(resp) {
    if (this.readyState == 1)
    this.abort();
    size = this.getResponseHeader("Content-length");
};
```

The problem is that even though if I check the value of *size* after the sentence

```
size = this.getResponseHeader("Content-length");
```

the value is the one I expect, in the main function its value is still 0 when it reaches this part of the code:

```
if (size > maxS)
    // Do something
```

I tried to figure out the answer by checking some other questions which I found in this website and I **guess** it has something to do with synchronization but I don't really know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images are all on the exact same server, right?  `XMLHttpRequest()` will not do cross-domain requests (without some new hoops that don't apply in a Greasemonkey context, anyway).

There are a few problems with that code:

1. It expects size to be set synchronously but calls `XMLHttpRequest()` asynchronously.
2. It aborts the request!  And too soon.  There is no good reason to abort a `HEAD` request.
3. It uses a "magic number" in an obscuring way.  Use the proper enumerated constant, when available.  EG `this.readyState == 1` is bad.  `this.readyState == this.OPENED` is better.

---

For synchronous operation, change `getFileSize()`.  Call it like so:

```
getFileSize (imgs[j].src);
```

Define it like so:

```
function getFileSize (address) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    request.open ('HEAD', address, false);  //-- false = Synchronous
    request.send (null);  

    size        = -666; // Error, or AJAX fail.
    if (request.status === 200) {  
        size    = request.getResponseHeader ("Content-length");
    }  
}
```

---

Notes:

1. For performance and user-friendliness reasons, it would be better to refactor the approach to use asynchronous AJAX.  But that's another question and less intuitive.
2. If the images are cross-domain, you will need to use `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` -- which operates slightly differently and does not work properly for synchronous AJAX (last I checked -- which was a couple months ago).

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer has been really helpful and instructive for me and the issue has been solved.
I'm sorry but I can't vote your answer because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Glad you got your issue solved!  Also, you may not be able to vote yet, but you can [check the check-mark next to this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it helped you.